# Extract specific value from blocks of data

Tags: awk, sed, xml

I have the blocks of data which are differentiated by the global Ids as below. I need to extract the last block of data with the highest id value, in the below example, `id="82"`.

```
<gc type="global" id="80" totalid="80" intervalms="315080.595">
---Remaining data---------
 </gc>
 <gc type="global" id="81" totalid="81" intervalms="315080.595">
---Remaining data---------
 </gc>
 <gc type="global" id="82" totalid="82" intervalms="315080.595">
---Remaining data---------
 </gc>
```

I can perform the below. However, it will restrict the id value to be two digits only. How can I derive the last block of data without putting the digits restriction on id value.

```
data1=`grep "gc type="global"" abc.log| cut -c24-26|tail -n1`

lastdata="gc type="global"=$data1"

sed -n '/'"${lastdata}"'/,$p' abc.log>last_block_data.log
```

Comment: Are the data formatted in XML?

Comment: Not sure if I answer it right. The data is a common log file and the content within happens to occur between tags.

Comment: Does `xmllint` read the file without errors?

Comment: What if the highest id value is not the last block? Do you always want the last block, whatever its value, or do you always want the highest value, whatever its position?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to `cut` by `-c`haracter count. Instead, you can `cut` on a specified `-d`elimiter.

```sh
grep '^<gc type="global"' <infile | cut -d\" -f4
```

---

```
80
81
82
```

That gets only the 4th `"`-delimited field on a line. And so that field can be as many characters - or digits if you prefer - as you like, so long as none of them are double-quotes.

But you don't have to do that either if you want the whole line.

```sh
sed -e'/^<gc type="global"/!{g;/./q;d;}' -e'h;$!d' <infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data is a properly formatted and well formed XML document, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <gc type="global" id="80" totalid="80" intervalms="315080.595">
---Remaining data---------
 </gc>
  <gc type="global" id="81" totalid="81" intervalms="315080.595">
---Remaining data---------
 </gc>
  <gc type="global" id="82" totalid="82" intervalms="315080.595">
---Remaining data---------
 </gc>
</root>
```

The data for the `gc` node with an `id` attribute of `82` may be extracted using XMLstarlet like so:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//gc[@id="82"]' file.xml
```

This would get the contents of the relevant `gc` node, regardless of where in the document that node happens to be located.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F[=\"] '{
    a[FNR]=$0;
    if ($6>l && $0 ~ "<gc type=\"global\""){
        l=$6;f=1;s=FNR
    };
    if($0 ~ "</gc>" && f==1 ){
        e=FNR;f=0
    }}
    END{ 
    for (i=s;i<=e;i++) {
        print a[i]
}}'
```

This will print the block starts from `<gc type="global"` till  `</gc>` that has largest id.

All lines are saved to array `a` with key as `FNR`

First `if` will set the flag `f` and set the array key start variable `s` to `FNR` if the 6th field which is `id` greater than the previous one and the line has string `<gc type=\"global\"` .

Next `if` reset the flag and set the the array key end variable `e` to `FNR` if the line contans string `</gc>` and `f` equal to 1

In the `END` elements in array `a` are printed only when the key value between `s` and `e`.

Comment: This doesn't get the block of data. It will only print the `<gc...` line. The OP wants everything from that line to the `</gc>` tag.

Comment: Made changes to print entire block for largest id

Answer (score 0):

You could grep to find the lines with 'type="global"' and then use sed to extract the values within the quotes after 'id=':'

```
$ grep 'type="global"' /tmp/foo | sed -e 's/^.*id="\([0-9]*\)".*$/\1/'
80
81
82
...
```